# Vue.js Dynamic Value Word Wrap

Tags: css, vue.js

I don't know how to word-wrap this dynamic value that I inserted.

My code:

```
  <p style="width: 200px; word-wrap: break-word">
            <strong>Balance Name:</strong>
            {{ props.row.balance }}
          </p>
```

As you can see the balance name overlap the div.

https://gyazo.com/ec963664480742e94499f41ee575ab28

---

Example snippet but the problem does not appear here

```css
* { box-sizing: inherit; }
p { margin: 0 0 16px; }
```

```html
<p style="width: 200px; word-wrap: break-word">
  <strong>Balance Name:</strong>
  ITTS NEW ENROLLMENT AND TUITION FEE 2ND SEM 2019-2020
</p>
```

Comment: There's not enough here to debug but you really just need to find out what other styles are applying to your element. I suspect there's some flexbox styles (eg `flex-basis`) that are overriding the `width` style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believer, currently there is this property applied by the style library that you are using:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

if it's true then you can try removing `word-wrap: break-word` and just do like this:

```
<p style="width: 200px; white-space: normal;">
  <strong>Balance Name:</strong>
  {{ props.row.balance }}
</p>
```